# vb.net: BackgroundWorker1_DoWork not working

Tags: vb.net

I add commend on BackgroundWorker1 but is now working
on Upload_IMG() i add **Await** and i think problem from Await
I need call (Upload_IMG()) with async sub on background but isn't working

any body have any idea

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
          If TXT_R = "insta" Then
                ImageFileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Temp\184218523.jpg"
                TXT_insta = "How are you"
                Upload_IMG()
            End If
End Sub

Private Async Sub Upload_IMG()


              If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageFileName) = False Then
            Dim bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ImageFileName)
            Dim image = New InstaImageUpload With {
                .ImageBytes = bytes,
                .Uri = ImageFileName
            }

            Dim caption = TXT_insta.Trim
            Dim response = Await InstaApi.MediaProcessor.UploadPhotoAsync(image, caption)
            If response.Succeeded Then
                Label2.Text = "okkkk"
                Telegram.bot.messag_reply = "SENT"
                TXT_insta = ""
                irt = 0
                MessageBox.Show("Success", "Your image successfully uploaded")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Error", "error while sending image\r\n" + response.Info.Message)

            End If
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: ...and what error, on what line, are you getting?

Comment: Where's the BackGroundWorker? Are you calling an `async sub` method (`Upload_IMG()`) from the `DoWork` handler? You either use the async/await pattern or BackGrounWorker. Pick the one you're more comfortable with.

Comment: I need call (Upload_IMG()) with async sub on background but isn't working

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `Async`/`Await` then you should learn how it works. You apparently need to await that `UploadPhotoAsync` method and that's why your `Upload_IMG` method is declared `Async`. If you'd read about how it works though, you'd know two things:

1. Don't use `Async Sub` except for event handlers.
2. Use `Await` when calling an asynchronous method unless you specifically don't want to.

That means that your method should be declared like this:

```vb
Private Async Function Upload_IMG() As Task
```

and then called like this:

```vb
Await Upload_IMG()
```

If things still don't work as you expect then, instead of repeatedly saying "it doesn't work", explain exactly what you expect and exactly what actually happens.

Comment: Thank you for reply ,  i have try your answer but i's not uploading , is i call from button it's will be upload

Comment: @gezir, Yes replace `Sub Backgroundworker1_DoWork()` with `Async Sub Button1_Click()` and Call `Await Upload_IMG()`